# Windows 21H2 Defender Firewall Service not starting when Non-US language (set by registry key)

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I have a problem with Windows Defender under Windows 10 Enterprise (21H2) with Cumulative Patch from 08 and / or 09 2022.

I created an offline Setup with Microsoft Deployment Workbench to install that Windows (which is working great). (I have already integrated the September 22 cumulative Patch).

When Windows is installed everything is running fine (also the Windows Defender Firewall service).

Now I want to add German Language pack. I install the language.cab via Powershell (Add-WindowsPackage -Online). That is also working fine.

When I restart now - the Defender Firewall Service is automatically starting - everything Good.

Now I switch to German via Registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MUI\Settings\PreferredUILanguages (Value will be set to de-DE)

When I now restart - everything is German and works but the Windows Defender Service does not start anymore (although it is still set to automatic start)

When I manually start it - it throws errors in the event log (something like ‚Element Not found‘)

When I switch the reg key back to ‚en-US‘ and restart - the service is starting again.

What is also confusing me:
When I install the OS with August 2022 Patch, then I install the German Language pack, then I switch to German (Service is not starting). Then I apply the September 2022 Patch via Windows Update / WSUS and restart - now the Windows Defender Service starts (with German UI active)..

I don’t know which data / logs might help - so I haven't attached anything. But of course i can provide more info when somebody tells me what I should provide.

Any ideas appreciated to troubleshoot this down